# UITextView with Check Boxes

Tags: ios, swift

I want to create a check list app with UIText View , So need to call listeners on tap of the check boxes. Also I need to place those Check boxes with left alignment to the text the user gives. Is there any way to accomplish this in Swift???

Comment: What have you tried so far? Anything to build on?

Comment: You can go through https://github.com/hpique/HPTextViewTapGestureRecognizer. Just try it.

Comment: why you want to create checkboxes in textview??

Comment: I would suggest you look at using a table view

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Check below code:

```
    textView.layer.borderColor = UIColor.gray.cgColor
    textView.layer.borderWidth = 1.0

    textView.textContainerInset = UIEdgeInsets(top: 8, left: 8, bottom: 0, right: 8)

    // Create Button Programmatically
    let button = UIButton(frame: CGRect(x: 8, y: 8, width: 18, height: 18))
    button.setTitleColor(UIColor.red, for: .normal)
    button.setImage(#imageLiteral(resourceName: "check"), for: .normal)
    button.setImage(#imageLiteral(resourceName: "uncheck")  , for: .selected)
    button.addTarget(self, action: #selector(buttonCheckUncheckTapped), for: .touchUpInside)
    button.clipsToBounds = true
    button.layer.cornerRadius = 9

    // Create Exclusion Path to avoid text overlapping.
    let path = UIBezierPath(rect: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: button.frame.width, height: button.frame.height))
    textView.textContainer.exclusionPaths = [path]
    textView.addSubview(button)
```

[image]

Comment: Is there anyway to get the checkbox in text form, when calling ```[textView text]```? Because if not, how could you save the checkbox state as part of the string (if the user is editing it and adding further checkboxes).